# UnPack NuGet package that gets created on build

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, nuget, csproj

I am trying to unpack the nuget package that gets created during the build.

My `Directory.Build.props` file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <RestorePackagesPath>C:\packages</RestorePackagesPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
        <PackageOutputPath>C:\LocalNuGetPackages</PackageOutputPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <Version>1.0.0.1</Version>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Target Name="UnPack" AfterTargets="Pack">
        <Exec Command="nuget install $(PackageId) -Version $(PackageVersion) -Source C:\LocalNuGetPackages -OutputDirectory C:\packages" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

But this gives a different directory structure as Visual Studio is doing it.

Visual Studio produces the following directories

```
C:\packages\$(PackageId)\$(PackageVersion)\
```

But the used command (nuget install) produces

```
C:\packages\$(PackageId).$(PackageVersion)\
```

Is there a way to call the Visual Studio "internal" nuget to get the same directory structure, or am I missing an argument that enables this structure?
Currently I am using the nuget.exe from here https://www.nuget.org/downloads which I have added to PATH in my system variables.

Side note, I am not trying to install the NuGet package to any project, I am just looking to unpack it like Visual Studio does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was pointed out in the [github issue](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/10560) created by @Perry the command I was actually looking for was

```
nuget add "C:\LocalNuGetPackages\castle.core.4.4.0.nupkg" -Source C:\packages -expand
```

Instead of

```
nuget install castle.core -Version 4.4.0 -Source C:\LocalNuGetPackages -OutputDirectory C:\packages
```

The `add` command lacks the ability to fetch the nuget package from a "source" (eg. NuGet.org or C:\LocalNuGetPackages) and you already need the `*.nupkg` downloaded and ready to unpack.

But this lack of ability is irrelevant in my situation, since upon build I am creating the `*.nupkg` and they are ther for me to unpack.

Don't get confused with the argument being called `-Source` in the `add` it is actually the equivalent of `-OutputDirectory` for the `install` command.

So for other users/cases it would be desirable to have the `install` command do the different directory structure, but for me `add` was what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

That is designed by that. global nuget caches always make the nuget path like `package_id/version/xxx`. That's the way VS IDE unpacks NuGet packages into the global cache mechanism.

And when you use `nuget install` or packages folder under the solution folder by `packages.config`, it actually likes `package_id.version/xxx`.

This difference is not what we can handle and can belong to the design itself. So I have [reported the issue to the Team](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/10560).

You could vote it and add any comments if I did not describe it in detail. Hope it could solve your confusion as soon as possible.